# Implementing vector multiplication in java

Tags: java

Currently I'm trying to implement a way to be able to use vector- and matrix-multiplication in java, right now I have the code:

```
package ai2;

public class MyMatrix {
    int[][] alpha;
    int a;
    int b;
    int rowsB;
    int colsB;

    public MyMatrix(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        alpha = new int[a][b];
        for (int k = 0; k < a; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < b; l++) {
                alpha[k][l] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void insertValue(int o, int q, int z) {
        this.alpha[o][q] = z;
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int k = 0; k < a; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < b; l++) {
                System.out.print(this.alpha[k][l] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void multiplyMatrix(MyMatrix B) {
        MyMatrix created = new MyMatrix(this.a, B.b);
        for (int m = 0; m < a; m++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < b; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; k < this.a; l++) {
                    myMatrixC[i][j] += myMatrixA[i][k] * myMatrixB[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyMatrix a = new MyMatrix(2, 2);
        a.insertValue(0, 0, 1);
        a.insertValue(1, 1, 1);
        a.print();
        MyMatrix b = new MyMatrix(2, 2);
        b.insertValue(0, 0, 1);
        b.insertValue(1, 0, 1);
        // System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

The problem is my multiplyMatrix method, it takes a MyMatrix object but I cant reach the values using for example:

```
MyMatrixA[k][l]
```

I need some sort of idea to reach those values or perhaps a smarter implementation, I cannot use packages outside of java, thankful for any help!

Comment: Do you mean `MyMatrixA.alpha[k][l]`?

Comment: Thank you sir for your comment, it was the first but nothing to upvote, really appreciated tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets in Java are only for accessing array elements.

Your syntax there will not compile, and you cannot access your matrix elements that way.

Why don't you just implement a `getAlpha` getter in your `MyMatrix` class that returns the value for `alpha` (or better, a copy thereof, to ensure immutability)?

You could then reference it with `theMatrixInstance.getAlpha()[k][l]`.

You could also simplify a bit and implement a `get` method taking two indices.

That would allow you to check whether the given indices are within the bounds of your two-dimensional array and throw a custom exception (or return some default value) rather than the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` you'd otherwise get.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
myMatrixC[i][j] += myMatrixA[i][k] * myMatrixB[k][j];
```

with

```
created.alpha[i][j] += this.alpha[i][k] * B.alpha[k][j];
```

Or better yet, replace

```
MyMatrix created = new MyMatrix(this.a, B.b);
```

with

```
MyMatrix A = this;
MyMatrix C = new MyMatrix(this.a, B.b);
```

then you can do

```
C.alpha[i][j] += A.alpha[i][k] * B.alpha[k][j];
```

Which reads a little more clearly.

Finally, no need to initialize `alpha` with 0's in your constructor, this happens automatically.